# accessing virtualhost svn server through ssh tunnel

Tags: svn, virtualhost, ssh-tunnel

I'm facing the following problem: I need to access a svn depot (https) from a machine which block port 443 output. I have a normal user shell access. I can successfully do a ssh tunnel like that:

```
ssh -L 1234:mysvnhost.blabla.com:443 user@mymachinewhichhasaccesstoport443
```

Unfortunately the destination machine (mysvnhost.blabla.com) uses virtualhost. I guess that in order to work I need to add something like that

```
mysvnhost.blabla.com 127.0.0.1
```

in /etc/hosts of the machine which block port 443
but I don't have a root access to this machine.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I have asked the sysadmin to add the entry in /etc/hosts and it's working fine. Anyway I'm still interested in a solution which doesn't involve a root user.

Answer (score 2):

A solution could be to use a local ssl proxy and translate `localhost`/`127.0.0.1` by `mysvnhost.blabla.com`, some java proxies can handle *SSL* and *hostname translation*, else you can code it by yourself with `socat`